# Wordpress Get Template part

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Going trough a WordPress template i found the get template

```
<?php 
            if ( is_home() ) {
                get_template_part('home', 'featured'); 
                get_template_part('home', 'recent');
            }
        ?>
```

which calls certain template parts when the home page is displayed.

Is there a way to use the same function for certain pages? For example for `domain-name.com/contact` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`is_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) to determine the page. For example:

```
if ( is_page('contact') ) {
    get_template_part('home', 'featured'); 
    get_template_part('home', 'recent');
}
```

The parameter to the function can be the Page ID, Page Title or Page Slug.

Comment: so the custom url works as basicly as an id ? sweet, thank you Tom :)